I need unique word count that starts with P, that word can be in multiple rows or in a multiple columns in a text/excel file using python
I need unique word count that starts with P, that word can be in multiple rows or in multiple columns in a text file using python. An example is mentioned below.
Input:
P000013BP000005BP000010BP000045B
P000013BP000045BP000011A
IA1

Expected output:
P000013B 2
P000005B 1
P000010B 1
P000045B 2
P000011A 1


Do the input lines literally start with "Line"?

Given a text file input.txt in the stated format then it's just:
import re

stats = dict()

with open("input.txt") as data:
    for line in data:
        for p in re.findall(r"P\d+", line):
            stats[p] = stats.get(p, 0) + 1
for i, t in enumerate(stats.items(), 1):
    print(f"Line {i}:", *t)

Output:
Line 1: P001 2
Line 2: P003 2
Line 3: P004 1
Line 4: P086 1


I think Line number in the example confused. However, i got the desired output after tweaking last line to print(*t)
P001 2
P003 2
P004 1
P086 1
Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Starting from a DataFrame, you can use str.extractall and value_counts:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['P001P003', 'P004P001P086P003']})

out = df['col'].str.extractall(r'(P\d+)')[0].value_counts()

Or, a variant with str.split and explode to only consider the P as split point:
out = df['col'].str.split(r'(?<=.)(?=P)').explode().value_counts()

Output:
P001    2
P003    2
P004    1
P086    1
Name: count, dtype: int64

Or, if you have a text file, using pure python:
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    counts = Counter(re.findall(r'P[^P\s]*', f.read()))

print('\n'.join(f'{k} {v}' for k,v in counts.items()))

Output:
P000013B 2
P000005B 1
P000010B 1
P000045B 2
P000011A 1

Input filename.txt:
P000013BP000005BP000010BP000045B
P000013BP000045BP000011A
IA1


Yes i have it in text file. The output you mentioned has extra words like counter, braces.. etc.
I got desired output now. Thanks for your answer.

@sivaarumugam can you clarify your comment? What exactly is your input? Please edit the question and be explicit.

I edited the question can you please check now.

@sivaarumugam the exact generalization is still unclear, but assuming words starting with P, see update for the pure python version. I've left the pandas version as-is but you could use the first variant with the same r'(P[^P\s]*)' regex.
